# Ошибка при установке Woocomerce на Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Здраствуйте,у меня есть проблема при установке woocomerce на wordpress.Я хочу скачать woocomerce на чистый wordpress с оригинальной темой twenty seventeen,далее начинается установка и спустя примерно минуту на иконке установки пишет "обновление не удалось",и сверху вылазит надпись

"Установка не удалась: На сайте возникла критическая ошибка. Пожалуйста, проверьте входящие сообщения почты администратора для дальнейших инструкций.Узнайте больше про отладку в WordPress."

на почту соответственно ничего не приходит,сервер на локальном хостинге openserver,заходил в здоровье сайта все в норме.Зараннее спасибо.

[image: ошибка]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо отредактировать wp-config.php

Строку

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

заменить на

```
define('WP_DEBUG', TRUE);

define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );

define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', TRUE);
```

Так Вы включите отображение ошибок на сайте.

Более подробно описано в гайде по дебагу в Wordpress - https://wp-kama.ru/id_7791/debag-v-wordpress-wp_debug.html

Comment: Здраствуйте,отображение ошибок включил,ничего не изменилось,осталось так как есть,новых данные не появилось.

Comment: @misterwordpress включите еще параметр define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true ); для ошибок в логи и смотрите ошибки в wp-content/debug.log

Comment: я так понял у меня проблема с интернетом,вот логи           "[26-Nov-2020 14:28:11 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in W:\domains\wordpress\wp-admin\includes\class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 82"    можно ли как то ускорить загрузку,без вмешательство к провайдеру или прям нужно,менять интернет,у меня он слабый Ростелеком.

Comment: @misterwordpress поставьте в .htaccess php_value max_execution_time 18000